Couldn't revoke authorization on MIUI
I have been trying to disable the authorizations like the Updator or msa through Password & Security in Settings on MIUI.
But unfortunately I have been getting the same error message every time "Couldn't revoke authorization" even after trying again and again since ages. Can someone help me fix that problem?
I think that it's because of the Android-system is actually blocked by a kind of firewall, as I see it's not even trying to revoke the services, though my device in connected to the internet.
I am using the Xiaomi Pad 6 with the Global version of MIUI 13, I also have Xiaomi Pad 5 (Global version of MIUI) but with same problem on HyperOS.
This isn't my first time disabling the authorizations as I've done that before on Redmi Note 10 Pro but with the Indian version of MIUI
